# Unit testing for embedded C development

Tags: c, unit-testing, embedded

Dumb question: what unit test framework do you use for embedded development?
There are was a question about unit test frameworks for C, but it was old, and not embedded oriented.

Comment: Can't you use C++ (and a modern C++ unit testing framework) in your tests? Your production code would still be C, but the tests would be in C++.

Comment: Embedded is a very wide notion: C on 2KB ATTiny is embedded development. C on a Cortex A9 with 1GB RAM and 1GB flash is still embedded developement. You should tell us what is your target processor and RAM.

Comment: AVRs as minimum (ATMega256RFR2), later another platform.

Comment: [This](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/21730/2308) question and answers on electronics.stackexchange.com has some further info which may be relevant.

Comment: It depends on your situation of course, but I have been able to test embedded C code in the same way I would test other C++ code.  As long as it's compliant to the standard, and you provide the `extern "C"` wrapper there should be nothing stopping you from using a modern C++ testing framework.

Comment: Some time ago I wrote a thorough tutorial on the topic: [Unit-testing (embedded) C applications with Ceedling](https://dmitryfrank.com/articles/unit_testing_embedded_c_applications); I use these techniques in a bunch of projects, and I'm quite happy so far.

Answer (score 7):

If I only take this part of your question : *What unit test framework do you use for embedded development?*, then I answer Google Test. It requires a C++-compatible compiler, but is suitable for testing C code.

We use it for all our embedded development: TI C67x DSP (production code is 100% C, we use only C++ for gtest), VxWorks on x86 and Linux on ARM.

**Edit**: You wrote in your comments that your platform is an ATMega. I do not think `gtest` will fit in a 8 bits MCU, even a big one. You may have two solution:

- If you have a lot of code that is independent from the MCU hardware itself, you can try to test this code on a computer, mocking (i.e. simulating) the hardware-related parts. This solution will only make unit tests (not integration tests), requires your code to have a clear frontier between what is tightly related to the hardware and between what is not...
- Try a testing framework explicitly designed for MCU. [µCUnit](http://www.ucunit.org/) documentation seems clear, I have never tried it... it may worth the try.

Comment: Yes, it's related, but it's old - some tolls look like at inactive state, or opposite still unstable.

Comment: You are true, it is quite old.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one - [MinUnit -- a minimal unit testing framework for C](http://www.jera.com/techinfo/jtns/jtn002.html)

Simple, yet very handful